# C# Entity Framework. Simplify query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

How to simplify the next query to database:

```
public Plan? Get(DateTime now)
{
    return context.Plans
        .Where(x => IsActivePlan(x, now)) // 1 condition

        .Where(x => IsPlolongingPlan(x, now)) // 2 condition
        
        .OrderBy(x => x.StartedAt)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

What I need:
If there are objects after 1 condition, then execute "OrderBy" and return the first element. If there are no objects, then go to the 2 condition, execute "OrderBy" and return "FirstOrDefault". I don't want the objects to be taken at once by two conditions.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this

```
public Plan? Get(DateTime now)
{
    return context.Plans.Where(x => IsActivePlan(x, now)).OrderBy(x => x.StartedAt).FirstOrDefault()
        ?? context.Plans.Where(x => IsPlolongingPlan(x, now)).OrderBy(x => x.StartedAt).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

because you don't want two conditions been true at once you have to:

```
return context.Plans
        .Where(x => (IsActivePlan(x, now) && !IsPlolongingPlan(x, now)) ||
                    (!IsActivePlan(x, now) && IsPlolongingPlan(x, now)))            
        .OrderBy(x => x.StartedAt)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Nice thought as the second part will only be executed if the first is null.

Comment: I agree to this, _if_ the following statement is always true: `IsActivePlan(x, now) != IsPlolongingPlan(x, now)`. (Based on the method names, it should be :) )

Comment: @AstridE.'s approach is more better and intelligence

Comment: It's not a different approach, just a sidenote to yours, which I support!

Answer (score 1):

You can check before if exist any

Like this:

```
            var result = null;
            if (context.Plans.Any(x => IsActivePlan(x, now)))
            {
                result = context.Plans.Where(x => IsActivePlan(x, now))
                    .OrderBy(x => x.StartedAt)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                result = context.Plans.Where(x => IsPlolongingPlan(x, now))
                    .OrderBy(x => x.StartedAt)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }
```